# Is it possible in Overpass to filter out the points that are in the nth position in the line?

Tags: overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I want to find all `fixme=continue` that are neither the last nor the first point of the line.  Is it possible to filter in Overpass by position number in the list of line points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with Overpass 0.7.56, this feature has appeared:

> For your convenience, there is a shortcut integrated in the recurse
> filter, as shown in [this example](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/RtF). Negative values are counted from the
> tail of the way, i.e. -2 is the last but one node of the way:
>
> ```
> way(60538085); 
> node(w:1,-2); 
> out geom;
> ```

https://dev.overpass-api.de/blog/total_0_7_56.html

In total, for the original problem, you can first get all the points of the lines, and then discard the first and last ones:

```
node[fixme=continue]({{bbox}});
(._;<;);
(._;>;)->.x;

node.x[fixme=continue]->.a;
node(w.x:1,-1)[fixme=continue]->.b;
(.a; - .b;);

out geom;
```